# Help parsing and translating this sentence with を at the end

Tags: translation, meaning, manga, parsing, sports

Context: an aggressive and violent boxer (Riku) is going to fight against an evasive opponent that is really good at dodging punches and who always tries to win on points rather than KOs. Riku's trainer tells him:

> 長引けばお前のパターンを読まれて不利になってく　かと言って焦ればカラ回る
>
> まっ　相手に一発はねェし好きに探ってこい　ヤツのボクシングと…　てめーが覚える気味の悪さってのを

I understand the first sentence but not the second. I think that everything that comes before を is the object of 探ってこい, so I tried to rearrange the sentence in this way:

> まっ　相手に一発はねェしヤツのボクシングと…てめーが覚える気味の悪さってのを
>   好きに探ってこい

Is it correct? Then I tried translating it:

> Anyway, your opponent hasn't got strong punches, so you can freely probe his boxing style and *the bad feeling you know/remember* (?).

Even if I put it like this, I still can't make sense of the part in italic. [Here you can see the whole page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WRDtK.jpg). Please ask if you need more context. Thank your for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have *parsed* this sentence perfectly. But here 覚える means not "to remember" but "to feel". It's [the third definition on jisho](https://jisho.org/search/%E8%A6%9A%E3%81%88%E3%82%8B) and [the third definition on デジタル大辞泉](https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/jn/32917/meaning/m0u/%E8%A6%9A%E3%81%88%E3%82%8B/).

てめーが覚える気味の悪さを探れ in this context roughly means "You will feel the opponent is eerie, and you should think and realize why you feel so during the game".